# Ignore property and Table-per-concrete-class (TPC) mapping

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I have abstract base class lets call it A

A

- Code
- Name
- Type

And then concrete types B and C

B has a Type column in database
but C does not since it can only be of one type, the C concrete class overrides this property like

```
public override Types Type
{
    get { return Types.Foo; }
    set {  }
}
```

I have ignored the Type property in the C configuration like

```
public class CConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<C>
{
    public CConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(t => t.Code);

        Map(l => l.MapInheritedProperties());

        ...

        Ignore(r => r.Type);

        ToTable("C");
    }
}
```

This gives error

> Additional information: You cannot use Ignore method on the property
>   'Type' on type 'C' because
>   this type inherits from the type
>   'A' where this property is
>   mapped. To exclude this property from your model, use
>   NotMappedAttribute or Ignore method on the base type.

If I ignore it on the base class I instead get

> Additional information: The property 'Type' is not a declared property
>   on type 'B'. Verify that the property has not been explicitly
>   excluded from the model by using the Ignore method or
>   NotMappedAttribute data annotation. Make sure that it is a valid
>   primitive property.

Adding `NotMappedAttribute` to C's Type property does nothing and I do not want to use attrobutes which fluent mapping aims to remove

**edit:** One ugly solution is to create an internal Property that maps to the DB and then have a public one that is ignored. The override for class B just points to the internal one

Comment: I don't see how this would be semantically possible since by ignoring a base property you are no longer implementing the interface of the base type. TPH, TPT and TPC are called `inheritance strategies` for good reason. I think the first error message pretty much says it all. As its basically saying " you need to change the interface" if you want to do that. Adding properties is obviously not a problem as the interface remains in tact but ignoring a base property on a derived type is like "C is not an A". Remember these classes have to be materialized back into .NET type system.

Comment: Well, I dont see how it should not be the responsiblity of the ORM to support this. My edit solves the problem but in a not so nice way. Having a property on the base class thats only in some cases is actually connected to the database feels pretty standard to me

Comment: Do other ORMs support this? I'm not sure. I'll keep an eye on this thread and maybe be proved wrong but to me the error and lack of support is entirely consistent with what an interface / contract is. By ignoring base class properties, on derived classes, you essentially have a crocodile that is not an animal. I think it is that kind of support that ends up bloating frameworks and is something to be avoided. It's not a simple thing to "just do".

Comment: I'm not ignoring properties on base class, im overriding it on the sub class. Make full sense in a polymorphic point of view, and EF is a ORM right? It should help in domain driven design right?